# How to install a sub panel?

Tags: electrical, wiring, subpanel

How to install subpanel?
Wired 888 stranded no ground to a 125a 8 space 16 circuit sub panel ( not purchased yet) in a metal greenhouse (hoophouse). 40amp breaker from main. Total run 120'. The wiring  is the only thing in place right now. Total load i can conceive of is less than 30a. Greenhouse will have 28 interconnected galvanized pipes concreted in @ 2' deep. There are no metalic or water connected from one building to the next, only the 888 in 3/4" pvc conduit. I have a surge breaker  that covers main panel. .

1. Should the sub. Be mounted directly to the hoophouse metal structure or would it create problems for the panel in a lighting strike? or separate it with rubber bushings?
2. Should i have separate ground rods for subpanel and hoophouse? How many  do i need?
3. Do i need a gfci that covers the subpanel?
4. I think I don't need a larger sub. because I am limited to 40 amps. Any specific instructions on purchasing or wiring sub?

Comment: A ground has been required to subpanels for decades...

Comment: welcome. On this website we prefer one question per question. You currently have 4. You need to do some preparation work (read more, consult local code inspector / building permit center) and ask one specific question or hire a professional

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about # 1. But I'll answer the others:

> 2 Should I have separate ground rods for subpanel and hoophouse? How many do I need?

Yes. Standard practice is two ground rods. In most places you can instead use one ground rod with a test. But the test is more work/cost than simply installing a second ground rod.

> Do I need a gfci that covers the subpanel?

I don't think you need one that covers the subpanel itself. But you do need GFCI on the individual circuits. Your options include:

- GFCI/breaker in the main panel feeding the subpanel.
- GFCI/breaker backfed in the subpanel as a disconnect. Except that it might not work "backwards". And I don't know of any panels with a main breaker that can be GFCI/breaker.  **But you do need a disconnect, more on that below.**
- GFCI/breakers on individual circuits.
- GFCI/deadfront on individual circuits, between the subpanel and the first device in each circuit.
- GFCI/receptacles as the first device in each circuit.

GFCI/breakers are generally much more expensive than GFCI/deadfront or GFCI/receptacles, but GFCI/breakers are a simpler installation, and sometimes (240V circuits) the only choice.

> I think I don't need a larger sub. because I am limited to 40 amps. Any specific instructions on purchasing or wiring sub?

First of all, ignore "circuits". Since you will almost definitely need GFCI on everything, you can't use half-size breakers except along with GFCI/receptacles. Spaces are cheap, replacing everything later is not.

Consider an actual "main" panel. Which is functionally the same as a subpanel except:

- It includes a main breaker, and that will function as a disconnect.
- It typically comes (but not always) without a separate ground bar, so you may need to add a ground bar. That's because in a subpanel neutral and ground are kept separate but in a traditional main panel they can be combined. But that is not an absolute - some main panels come with a ground bar and some subpanels may *not* include a ground bar.

A main panel often comes as a package including extra (non-GFCI) breakers, which can make up for a lot of the difference between a subpanel and a main panel. Plus since you don't have to buy/install a separate disconnect (or put in a large backfed breaker to use as a disconnect), a main panel really doesn't end up costing much more than a subpanel, **and you get a lot more spaces**. It is usually not hard to find a main panel with main breaker and a few branch circuit breakers for under $100.

##### Ground

In addition to the ground rods, you **must** have a ground wire from your main panel to your subpanel. That has been a code requirement for a long time. Add a green or bare copper 10 AWG wire, or a 8 AWG aluminum wire (if you are using aluminum for hots/neutral).

##### Wire

It is not clear whether you installed 8 AWG copper (generally OK for up to 50A) or aluminum (40A). Based on "stranded" and "no ground wire", I assume it is individual wires and not cables. For future reference (e.g., if you ever want to upgrade to more than 50A), you can use aluminum instead of copper and save a lot of money. See [this chart](https://www.cerrowire.com/products/resources/tables-calculators/ampacity-charts/), 75 C column, for details.

Comment: The metallic frame should be *bonded* to the GES (Ground Electrode System) (and that implies that the panel can be mounted directly to the frame.)

Comment: And 10 AWG copper (or 8 AWG aluminum) is sufficient for up to 60A supply (Table 250.122) for the wire between the main panel and sub-panel, (barring oversize sub-panel supply conductors triggering an upsize requirement for the ground.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal Thank you for that. In a quick search earlier I couldn't find that table and what I did find seemed to say 8 AWG copper, though that didn't sound quite right.

Comment: But the ground rod is only needed in this case because the sub panel is in a separate building???  And if the sub panel were in the same building as the main panel, than a separate ground rod is not needed?

Comment: @SteveSh correct. Ground wire always required. Getting rods one set per building.